# Error 'cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'UInt'

Tags: swift, healthkit

On the line

```
var anchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: Int(HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor))
```

I get the red flag error

> cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Uint'

I had copy-pasted the code from another Xcode project, which brought no error for this line in the other project (reading heart rate on watchOS only).

Any ideas?

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

//State of the app - is the workout activated
var workoutActive = false

// define the activity type and location
var workoutSession : HKWorkoutSession?
let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(fromString: "count/min")
var anchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: Int(HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what you have to do. Just change the code:

```
var anchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: UInt(HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor))
```

You need to change `Int` for `UInt`, which is what `HKQueryAnchor` expects.

Comment: To those of us beginners in coding, that's not obvious. UInt is an 'unsigned integer' I now know. Thanks to Eric D too, had figured that out while you were typing though, thank you for confirming!

Comment: @DimitriT I've deleted my comment since Vladimir has posted a correct answer. A tip: in Xcode, take the habit of doing ALT+CLICK on a variable/method/object/etc to see its type and signature. It's of great help in such situations, and for learning in general. :)

Comment: will do - thank you Eric D, great tip. Very good way to learn indeed.