# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UInt'

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield

I am trying to call insertspaceInExpiryDateTextField() function into textField() function and getting the above error.

// Making the Expiry Date Text Field take "/" after 2 digits.

```
func insertspaceInExpiryDateTextField(string: String,inout andPreserveCursorPosition cursorPosition: UInt) -> String {

    var stringWithAddedSpaces: String = ""
    for index in 0.stride(to: string.characters.count, by: 1) {
        if index != 0 && index % 2 == 0 {
            stringWithAddedSpaces += " "

            if index < Int(cursorPosition) {
                cursorPosition += 1
            }
        }
        let characterToAdd: Character = Array(string.characters) [index]
        stringWithAddedSpaces.append(characterToAdd)
    }
    return stringWithAddedSpaces
}
```

// Calling the above function into this function
// making the Expirey Date Field take only 4 digits....  Also giving "/" after 2 digits to divide month and year.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {



if textField == self.txt_expDate {

            self.insertspaceInExpiryDateTextField(textField.text!, andPreserveCursorPosition: (&UInt(range.length)))     // Here I get the error

            txt_expDate.text! = txt_expDate.text!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

            return ((txt_expDate.text?.characters.count)! >= 4 && range.length == 0) ? false : true
        }
}
```

// Everything else works fine, except the UInt error.

// I also checked with [Error 'cannot convert value of type 'int' to expected argument type 'UInt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663875/error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-int-to-expected-argument-type-uint) but no use..

Is there any particular line that I am going wrong ? Thanks 
Thanks

Comment: self.insertspaceInExpiryDateTextField(textField.text!, andPreserveCursorPosition: (&UInt(range.length)))     // Here I get the error

Answer (score 0):

The length property of NSRange is bridged as Int and not UInt in Swift (I have no idea why; [its NSUInteger in Objective C)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrange/1459537-length?language=objc).  You can check in a playground as follows:

```
print(type(of: NSRange(location: 0, length: 0).length))
```

Comment: To answer your confusion about why it's `Int` and not `UInt`: Swift convention is to use `Int` unless there's a strong reason against it, even for data that's never expected to be negative. This way there's less casting going on between various types of integers